# How to make a text view that changes it content depending on what button is clicked? (android,eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image]I have a page with buttons and I want to place a description bar for each button so when someone presses a button the text changes depending on what button was clicked.

So I tired setting the textviews and giving each one of them an id in a separate xml file except for the first one I wrote it in the main xml and wrote this code:

```
TextView dis;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.weapons);


    dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.k_k);
     ......

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.kk_btn:
        dis.setText(R.id.k_k);
        break;
    case R.id.ss_btn:
        sp.play(soundId2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        dis.setText(R.id.s_s);
        break;
    case R.id.hd_btn:
        sp.play(soundId2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        dis.setText(R.id.h_d);
        break;
```

but it doesn't work it writes false in the place where the text is supposed to be.

example:

it's something like a table with 2 columns, the first contains buttons the second contains the description of each button but the only description that is view is the description of the button clicked. so on the 2nd column the text changes depending on what button is clicked and it gets the text from an textview and each button has it's own.

Comment: what would be the expected result?

Comment: the text in my text view @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: can you be more clear with your expected output at least post some example

Comment: @Kerppag I added an example

Comment: could you post a picture.can i see your current GUI

Comment: @Kerppag i added pictures to explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your oncreate you creating a `textview` with a resource id of `R.id.k_k`

```
dis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.k_k);
```

and in your `onClick method` you are using `setText` with a resource id

```
dis.setText(R.id.k_k);
```

you can use of `array` for your description

```
String[] descriptionArray={"this is button 1","this is button 2"};

//set onclick listener to your button
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

            dis.setText(descriptionArray[0]);
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

            dis.setText(descriptionArray[1]);
    }
});
```

if you want to use the ids of your textview just make a `TextView array`

```
TextView[] textViewArray={(TextView)findViewById(R.id.k_k),(TextView)findViewById(R.id.h_d) };
```

to set the text to `dis TextView`

```
dis.setText(textViewArray[0].getText().toString());
```

Comment: can i use id rather than "this is button 1", "this is button 2".
like String[] descriptionArray={"R.id.kk","R.id.s_s"};

Comment: why do you want to use the id?

Comment: is R.id.kk a `TextView?`

Comment: because the real text is much longer than this and there are 24 buttons and each has it's own text size and text color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59395/discussion-between-ker-p-pag-and-user3896367).

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just to get description on the basis of button click then you can try this code.In this case I have get the button text so in you case you can get the description from the strings.

```
    result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            result.setText(btn1.getText().toString());


        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            result.setText(btn2.getText().toString());


        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't want to change the text on the button I want to change the text in an other place based on which button is clicked. I added picture to explain what I mean

Comment: I understand your problem but is that description in the same activity or different? If it is on the same activity than just store different strings for different buttons and get those strings on button click and set on the description.